# csproj error when transfer a project in vs 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, csproj

i developed a project in vs2013 and i want to work with this app in another computer with vs 2013 but when i copy project and open it in this computer my project don't load and show me this error

C:\Users\asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projectname\Projectname.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Projectname\Projectname.csproj

the propertygroup in csproj file is

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
```

i changed version from 10 to 12 or 13 but also i see error

Comment: Install https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/?

Comment: AjaxMinSetup should be installed

Answer (score 2):

As both @stijn and @user2399248 answered in the comments, [**Microsoft Ajax Minifier**](https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) (or more specific AjaxMinSetup.msi) needs to be installed on the computer.